# Kotlin and Gradle - Reading from stdio

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to execute my Kotlin class using the command:

```
./gradlew -q run < src/main/kotlin/samples/input.txt
```

Here is my **HelloWorld.kt** class:

```
package samples

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println("Hello, world!")

    val lineRead = readLine()
    println(lineRead)
}
```

Here is my **build.gradle.kts**:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    application
}

application {
    mainClassName = "samples.HelloWorldKt"
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

The code executes, but the data contained inside the input.txt file is not displayed. Here is the output I get:

```
Hello, world!
null
```

I want to be able to execute the gradlew command above and the input.txt stream be redirected to stdio. I can easily do that in C++. Once I compile my .cpp file, I can run:

```
./my_code < input.txt
```

and it executes as expected.

How can I achieve the same thing with Kotlin and Gradle?

**Update**: Based on [this answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-doesnt-system-in-read-block-when-im-using-gradle/3308/2), I've tried adding this to build.gradle.kts but it is not a valid syntax:

[image]

Comment: @CodeConfident Yes, I am sure. My problem is similar to this question: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-doesnt-system-in-read-block-when-im-using-gradle/3308/2

Comment: Sorry... I deleted my comment already. When I re-read it it just didn't make sense any more.

Comment: That link looks like a reasonable answer. Have you tried adding `run { standardInput = System.in }` to your build.gradle.kts? Same suggestion is here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-execute-a-java-application-that-asks-for-user-input/3264

Comment: why `build.gradle.kts` and not just `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 21):

AjahnCharles suggestion about `run { standardInput = System.in }` is correct, but to port it to kotlin-dsl you need a different syntax.
`run` in this case is the task name and you configure existing task of `application` plugin.
To configure existing task in kotlin-dsl you should use one of this ways:

```
val run by tasks.getting(JavaExec::class) {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

or

```
val run: JavaExec by tasks
run.standardInput = System.`in`
```

The upcoming version of Gradle 4.3 should provide [API for plugin writers](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2842) to read user input.

The reason of difference between of Groovy and Kotlin in this case because Groovy uses dynamic types, but in Kotlin you must specify task type to have autocompletion and just to compile config script

Comment: For reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configuring_tasks

Answer (score 1):

I finally settled on this (Gradle 7.1.1):

```
plugins {
    application
}

tasks.getByName("run", JavaExec::class) {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

I don't know enough Kotlin yet to judge whether this is equivalent to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662535/253921.

Answer (score 0):

## Almost, but this doesn't work :'(

### In Theory

My understanding: `< input.txt` sets the standard input for the gradlew process, but by default this is not forwarded to your program.

You want to add this to your build.gradle.kts:

```
run {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

**Sources:**
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-doesnt-system-in-read-block-when-im-using-gradle/3308/2
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-execute-a-java-application-that-asks-for-user-input/3264

---

### In Practice

These build configs look about the same to me, yet **Groovy works and Kotlin doesn't**. I'm starting to think that the Gradle Kotlin DSL doesn't support the `standardInput` term yet :/

[image: Gradle in Kotlin vs Gradle in Groovy]

Here's my working Groovy version if that's any help:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // api => exported to consumers (found on their compile classpath)
    // implementation => used internally (not exposed to consumers)
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

mainClassName = "samples.HelloWorldKt"

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

Comment: I have tried that already. But the code does not compile. I've attached a screenshot to the question.

Comment: I've (finally) recreated the problem. I made both a Kotlin build.gradle.kts and a standard build.gradle. The latter works provided the `run { ... }` is set. This makes me think the problem lies in importing the appropriate Java package into the Kotlin build script (I guess Groovy does this automatically). Nearly there... ^^

Comment: @Tiago - I'm afraid despite having it working with Intellij, kotlin command line, and gradle-groovy, I ***cannot*** work out how to make it work for gradle-kotlin, though based on the screenshot above you can probably tell I'm having more trouble than you! I hope you find an answer; this seems quite a useful thing to be able to do.

Comment: Yeah, I've spent hours on this as well. But it is good to know the Groovy version works. I might stick to that solution then. Thank you a lot for helping me look into this!

Comment: @Tiago - Honestly it was really good practice for me. Good to have a challenge to drive your learning ^^. I'd leave the question open to see if you get a better answer later. I'll be following it for sure!

Comment: `run {}` comes from the kotlin-stdlib and doesn't reference the `run` task.
`tasks.getByName<JavaExec>() { standardInput = System.in }` should do

Comment: @eskatos's suggestion works for me with one minor adjustment:

```tasks.withType<JavaExec>() { standardInput = System.`in` }```

Comment: @BruceHamilton Can we not be more surgical than setting `standardInput` for _every_ `JavaExec` task in the build? This works, and I'm grateful, but I'd like to do even better.

Comment: Aha! Even better! ``tasks.getByName("run", JavaExec::class) { standardInput = System.`in` }``. This way, we have fewer side-effects.