# Pipe into "gradle run"

Tags: shell, gradle

I want to do something along the lines of this:

```sh
echo "foobar" | ./gradlew run
```

I understand that [the `run` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks) calls [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:standardInput) which takes a [`standardInput` argument](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:standardInput). But wasn't able to use it via the commandline.

Is it possible pass my piped input stream to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the run task, set `standardInput` to be `System.in`

```
run {
  standardInput = System.in
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that I know the answer I found that my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747112/kotlin-and-gradle-reading-from-stdio which I couldn't find before, since I searched with different keywords.